# Import .data file in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have .data file contains tab separated list. I want to import this .data file into Python, I've seen there are so many libraries offer this feature, but can't really find one that easily to implement. Can you guys tell me how to load it, or any kind of library(best library) that could help me and how to use it? Thanks.

Comment: There is literally an [entire Python library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) made for reading csv files. Read the documentation and examples, attempt to write the code yourself, then come back with a specific question if you get stuck

Answer (score 4):

I agree with @CoryKramer. Please ask spezific questions to some parts of your code and where you stuck into...
For reading files there are a bunch of lib's existing in python (e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html), which are fairly easily to implement.

If you just want to read in a file an do what ever you want with it. You could try out

```
with open(foo.data) as myfile:
    myfile.read() #reads the entire file
    #do what ever you want
    # or 
    myfile.readline() #reads one line ...
    #do what ever you want
```

For further information read the input/output docs of the python doc (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)